# How to position one element top of another in css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a login form. So far I have managed to hardcode it but once I need to for ex. move one of the wrappers then I got to change every element position in that wrapper. How can I do it so that when moving icon, BG field and text, I only got to change position from one place?

HTML code:

```
    <div id="user-wrapper">
        <img id="userfield" src="images/fieldBG.png" alt="Username"> 
        <img id="usericon" src="images/userIcon.png" alt="Username"> 
        <p id="username">
            Username
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="pw-wrapper">
        <img id="pwfield" src="images/fieldBG.png" alt="Password"> 
        <img id="pwicon" src="images/pwIcon.png" alt="Password"> 
        <p id="pw">
            Password
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="login-wrapper">
        <img id="loginbtn" src="images/loginBtn.png" alt="Login">
        <p><a id="login" href="#">
            Login
        </p>
    </div>
```

CSS code:

```
    #user-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        top: 100px;
        width:1760px;
    }

    #usericon {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 740px;
    }

    #user-wrapper p { 
        position: absolute;
        top: 14px;
        left: 840px;
    }

    #pw-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        top: 120px;
        width:1760px;
    }

    #pwicon {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 740px;
    }

    #pw-wrapper p { 
        position: absolute;
        top: 14px;
        left: 840px;
    }

    #login-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        top: 140px;
        width: 1940px;
    }

    #login-wrapper p {
        position: absolute;
        top: 12px;
        left: 950px;
    }
```

The whole thing should look like this (but should be editable/positioned with an ease):

[image]

Thank You!

Comment: Please create a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Only use

```
 #usericon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
float: right;
    left: 740px;

}
```

Comment: This changes literally nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I managed to fix it myself.

Instead of width in the wrapper, I had to use left.

For ex.

```
#user-wrapper {
        position:relative;
        top:100px;
        left:0px;
}
```

Now I can just only change wrapper parameters top/left and it moves all items inside the wrapper div.